# Sum Of 2 Tables Query using SubQueries

Tags: mysql, optimization, join, subquery

My analytics team uses a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(ul.upload_bandwidth) + SUM(dl.download_bandwidth) AS total 
FROM 
    upload_facts ul, download_facts dl
WHERE 
    ul.date BETWEEN '2011-09-01' AND '2011-09-30' AND 
    dl.date BETWEEN '2011-09-01' AND '2011-09-30';
```

This is taking a very long time, over 12000 seconds, due to the "join" that is occurring.

Doing the sum from either table separately takes just a few seconds.  I am considering putting a sum per day into a separate table to speed this up.  However, I believe that it should be easier than that.

I want to eliminate the join and use subqueries to do this, however I'm not 100% sure how.  I tried the following, but it did not work.

```
SELECT 
    (select upload_bandwidth from upload_facts where date 
      BETWEEN '2011-09-01' AND '2011-09-30') 
    + 
    (select download_bandwidth from downloaded_facts where date 
      BETWEEN '2011-09-01' AND '2011-09-30');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(`upload_bandwidth`) FROM `upload_facts` WHERE `date` 
      BETWEEN '2011-09-01' AND '2011-09-30')
    +
    (SELECT SUM(`download_bandwidth`) FROM `download_facts` WHERE `date` 
      BETWEEN '2011-09-01' AND '2011-09-30')
AS `total`
```

That should do it.

Comment: Perfect.  Tested and the original query that took 13000+ seconds now takes 16.  Still some room for improvement, but a drastic change.

Comment: Is `date` an index in both tables? That'll help a lot, if it isn't.

Comment: Yes, it is.  Between the 2 tables, though, there are close to 9 M rows in that range.

Comment: I don't think you'll get much higher performance, then. That's a hell of a lot of rows.

Comment: The only way that I am thinking to improve is by creating a new table that contains just date,ul_total,dl_total.  And using a cron to populate it once a day.  Then, this query could simply query 30 rows.

Comment: 13000 seconds? 3.6 hours? Down to 16 seconds? You can probably just retire now. MySQL is now optimized.

Comment: Actually, 16 seconds is rather slow, now that I look at the query more closely. If your `date` fields are indexed and you're only querying 30 rows, that query should take a few milliseconds. I bet you have some other slow queries in the chain. Have you tested this query alone?
Other possibilities: table/row locking if the table is heavily queried by other users. Low on RAM?

Comment: Not necessarily. I have 3M forum posts on my site, and selecting ten posts on Page 3,000 of a thread ended up taking two seconds. Fixed that by selecting less data: get the ID of the first post on the page and then getting data with ID higher than that. Point is, lots of rows is going to be slow, regardless of `where` conditions.